# Is it a good practice to have parameter that is a global variable?

Tags: java, parameters, global-variables, global

I am an AP java student and while working on a project I wondered if it is a good practice to have a parameter that is a global variable. If you're wondering why I would want to do that well is so I wouldn't have to do this:

```
public class Circle {
private DrawingTool pen;
private SketchPad paper;

private double myX;
private double myY;
private double myWidth;
private double myHeight;

public Circle(double x, double y, double width, double height){
    paper = new SketchPad(500,500);
    pen = new DrawingTool(paper);

    x = myX; //I don't want to have to assign this every time
    y = myY; //like here
    width = myWidth; // and here
    height = myHeight; // and here
   }
}
```

is it allowed to just do the following:

```
    public Circle(double myX, double myY, double myWidth, double myHeight){
    paper = new SketchPad(500,500);
    pen = new DrawingTool(paper);
   }
}
```

and every time I pass the arguments to the parameter they will automatically be assigned to the global variables?

Comment: These are **not global variables** but instance variables. And this does seem to be bad from a common sense point of view: each Circle object will have its own SketchPad and DrawingTool? What if you'd like to have more circles on a SketchPad?

Comment: @ppeterka66 but I thought that since they can be accessed through any scope they can be called "global"

Comment: While being `private` they can be accessed only within the containing class.

Comment: No, they can **not** be accessed in any scope: not from a static scope inside the class, and no scopes from outside the class (unless you have public/protected/package protected getter methods). Also, one thing to mention: these are not static, so live and die with the object instance....

Comment: No, naming your method parameters the same as instance variables does not automatically _tie_ them to the instance variables. Instead, that would effectively hide the instance variables inside the method, and you are simply dealing with the formal parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> and every time I pass the arguments to the parameter they will automatically be assigned to the global variables?

No. There's nothing within Java which will make the "parameter to instance variable" (which isn't really "global") assignment automatic. Many IDEs have the ability to generate the code for you, but it does need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

An object stores its state in fields (variables in some programming languages) and exposes its behavior through methods (functions in some programming languages). Methods operate on an object's internal state and serve as the primary mechanism for object-to-object communication. Hiding internal state and requiring all interaction to be performed through an object's methods is known as data encapsulation — a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming.

Source: [What Is an Object?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)